# PyQt do not use system theme

Tags: python, pyqt6

[image][image]
So, the picture with the calculator is my system theme Numix Dark. And the picture with the button is a PyQt6 application. Problem: I want my app to look just like any other app in a Mate desktop with Numix Dark. Code:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *

from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        button = QPushButton("Press Me!")

        # Устанавливаем центральный виджет Window.
        self.setCentralWidget(button)
        print(QStyleFactory.keys())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

I tried searching on the internet. Tried using setup and configuration Qt apps.

Comment: You should probably ensure that you're using a proper theme integration: that screenshot looks like it's coming from GTK, so you have to check that as it is an issue specific to the OS. Besides, what's the output of that print? Also, clean up your imports, they are inconsistent.

Comment: Output of print ['Windows', 'Fusion']

Comment: Then you should look for the KDE version or, as said above, check your system setting for the Qt/GTK integration.

Comment: My system use Mate desktop(old gnome 2) with gtk4 and color theme Numix Dark.@musicamante
Qt takes the color of the system but not the appearance. For example, if you hover over a button in the same calculator, it will be red, and in Qt, the button will turn blue or black. Also note that the Qt button has a gradient but the calculator buttons do not.

Comment: I know what Qt does, and I already explained that the only way to make the program look as other "native" programs is by checking your system settings for the Qt/GTK integration. Qt cannot do that on its own, it completely depends on the OS configuration. You may need to install a related package, check the documentation of your distro.

Comment: I have already tried to install different packages (qt6-gtk-platformtheme, adwaita-qt6, qt5-qtconfig) and write configuration files, but this does not help me. I would be very happy if someone helped me.

Comment: I suggest you to contact the developers/support for Mate and/or your distribution. Sorry but, as said, this is an OS configuration problem and is not directly related to programming, especially because even if you find a solution for *your* case, that will not involve the programming aspects of your code, and it would only solve the problem for *your* situation.

Comment: No, I think it's the curvature of Qt6. Because applications on gtk4 work. So they somehow get the styles and use them. Thank you for all. Close this thread.

Comment: The gtk4 apps "work" because you installed a *gtk* theme. Qt on its own doesn't know anything about Gtk (or other toolkits), cannot use Gtk themes (unless a compatibility layer theme is installed) and by default comes only with 2 themes ("Windows", "Fusion"), plus specific platform themes on Windows/macOS. Additional themes can **only** be installed by the user, unless the OS or window manager already has them, otherwise Qt will always use the ones it gets when installed (by default, "Fusion"). I suggest you to do some research about linux themeing, as it seems you are a bit confused on that.

Comment: But on the screen, the button uses neither.

Comment: What you're showing in your first screenshot **is** a button drawn by the Fusion style. Do not confuse the palette with the style.

Comment: Now I use PyGTK, everything works, maybe later, after the project is completed, I will return to PyQt6.

Comment: Gtk and Qt are *very* different toolkits. Changing the toolkit "after the project is completed" is a terrible, terrible idea, especially considering the reason for that, which is a wrong one: you want your program to look what you *think* it should, but you don't seem to understand that you can do very little about that. Changing to Gtk will solve *your* needs, but people using a wm based on Qt will have the *opposite* problem; or, more probably, they would just not care at all. You choose a programming toolkit because it's valid and robust, not because it looks good with the theme of your OS.